# Displaying a linked list with multiple classes?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm not sure why my display function isn't working. My `cout` statement is stating something like

```
no match for operator << in std :: cout<<n->movieinventory::movienode::m
```

Any ideas?

```
class MovieInventory
{
 private:
 struct MovieNode          // the Nodes of the linked list
  {
     Movie m;              // data is a movie
     MovieNode *next;      // points to next node in list
  };

  MovieNode *movieList;    // the head pointer

  bool removeOne(Movie);   // local func, used by sort and removeMovie

  public:
  MovieInventory();

  bool addMovie(Movie);
  int removeMovie(Movie);
  void showInventory();
  Movie findMinimum();   // should be private, but public for testing
  void sortInventory();

  int getTotalQuantity();
  float getTotalPrice();

};
```

Display code:

```
void MovieInventory::showInventory()
{

MovieNode *n;

    for (n = movieList; n != NULL; n = n->next)
    cout <<  n->m;
}
```

Comment: Try importing the standard namespace, `using namespace std;`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - that will not help - see CodingMash's answer to understand the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data member `m` belongs to the `Movie` class. The `cout` with `<<` [operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) is overloaded only for the built in data types as int, char, float, etc. So it would not output the object of your user defined data type. You have to overload the `<<` operator for your own class for that.

If you do not want to overload the opeator <<, you have to output the data members of the Movie class one by one this way, provided they are publicy declared.

```
cout << n->m.var1 ;
cout << n->m.var2 ;
```

If data members of the Movie class are private, you would have to make getter functions for that.

```
cout << n->m.getvar1() ;
cout << n->m.getvar2() ;
```

Comment: hmm is there anyway to do it without overloading? i am not supposed to  add functionsl

Comment: i  also just tried this and its no good ... ' MovieNode *n;

    for (n = movieList; n != NULL; n = n->next)
     cout <<  n->m.sku << n->m.title << n->m.price << n->m.quantity;
}'

Comment: What does it do?
Post the complete interface of Movie class.

Comment: yes they were private but you helped greatly thanks again have a good nite and holiday